Using T1 Libertinus Fonts with pdfLaTeX: Missing Symbols Issue
I'm trying to use the T1 Libertinus and Libertinus Math fonts with pdfLaTeX for my thesis. However, I'm encountering an issue where some symbols are not being properly typeset, even though they should be available according to the libertinus1math documentation.
For example, in the following MWE, the \triangleleft symbol works, but the \triangledown symbol is not typeset:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\begin{document}

Here is a left triangle: \( \triangleleft \)

Here is a down triangle: \( \triangledown \)

\end{document}


The log file shows the following:

Missing character: There is no � in font libertinust1-mathsym!

I have also checked the .sty file in the symbols are defined there. Loading amssymb after the libertinust1math package will make the missing symbol work. However, I think this is not recommended?

The fact that it refers to an entry in the font, is not the same as that entry being available in the font.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

@daleif - As I explain in my answer, there's a naming issue error in the file libertinust1math.sty.

There appears to be a slight mistake in the file libertinust1math.sty: The instruction
\libus@MathSymbol{\triangledown}{\mathord}{symbols}{"D6}

points to an empty slot. The final argument, "D6, should actually be "D4. (Aside: The slots "D5 and "D6" are both empty.) Conversely, the macro named \bigtriangledown, defined via
\libus@MathSymbol{\bigtriangledown}{\mathord}{symbols}{"D4} 

should, in my opinion, be called \triangledown.
Unless you want to hand-edit the file libertinust1math.sty -- I wouldn't... -- to correct the naming issue at the source, I suggest you simply use \bigtriangledown in lieu of \triangledown.

I was trying to view the pfb in fontforge but could not remember what "D6 etc was referirng to

@daleif - I had to compare the list of \libus@... directives in libertinust1math.sty with the tables in libertinust1math.pdf -- in particular, with table libertinust1-mathsym (symbols) on page 8 of the pdf file -- in order to come up with the diagnosis.

Thanks for this!

The font libertinust1-mathsym is used for the symbols math group.
Here's the complete list of symbols from that font:

With \tracinglostchars=3, I get two errors from the lines
\libus@MathSymbol{\blacktriangledown}        {\mathord}{symbols}{"D5}
\libus@MathSymbol{\triangledown}             {\mathord}{symbols}{"D6}

that point to empty slots. They are preceded by
\libus@MathSymbol{\bigblacktriangledown}     {\mathord}{symbols}{"D3}
\libus@MathSymbol{\bigtriangledown}          {\mathord}{symbols}{"D4}

The relevant part of the font table is

I don't see how the symbols in slots "D3 and "D4 qualify for “big”.
Waiting for a fix you can add two equivalents.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}

\RenewCommandCopy{\triangledown}{\bigtriangledown}
\RenewCommandCopy{\blacktriangledown}{\bigblacktriangledown}

\begin{document}

Here is a left triangle: \( \triangleleft \)

Here is a down triangle: \( \triangledown \)

Here is a black down triangle: \( \blacktriangledown \)

\end{document}


However, the \triangleleft symbol doesn't blend with the others and it's taken from a different font, the one for the mathgroup letters. That's what the font provides…

+1. :-) Incidentally, the Opentype version of Libertinus Math, which may be accessed under LuaLaTeX by loading the unicode-math package and executing \setmathfont{Libertinus Math}, manages to correct the size of the symbol produced by \triangleleft. However, it continues to have a faulty default definition for \triangledown.

Thanks, this is an easy fix! Coincidentally, \blacktriangledown was the other symbol I was having issues with...
